# How to set multiple animations in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, animation, sprite, cocos2d-x

I'm currently starting with cocos2d-x to build games for blackberry/android/iOS.

I have the png and plist for the animations of a character created with texturepacker. I load them with `CCSpriteBatchNode` and `CCSpriteFrameCache` then I use a function created by me that loads all frames into an array of frames, then create a `CCAnimation` object and store the `CCAnimate` object created with the animation (code is more clear) the thing is that I have a function that detect touches and it is supposed to cycle through all animations, but it always crashes.

here is some code (this goes in the `init()`):

```
_batchNode = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("Character/girl.png");
_cache = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache();

_cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("Personajes/girl.plist");

_character = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("girlneutral1.png");
_character->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width * 0.1, winSize.height * 0.5));
_batchNode->addChild(_character, 1);
this->addChild(_batchNode);
createAnimation(0, "girlpush", 8, 0.15f);
createAnimation(1, "girlneutral", 4, 0.3f);
createAnimation(2, "girlcrash", 12, 0.3f);
createAnimation(3, "girljump", 12, 0.2f);
createAnimation(4, "girltrick", 12, 0.3f);

_character->runAction(CCRepeatForever::create( _charanimation[3]));

this->setTouchEnabled(true);
```

the function that loads the animations (_charanimation[] is just an array of CCAnimate):

```
void HelloWorld::createAnimation(int a, CCString animation_name, int frames, float delay)
{
    CCArray* animframes = CCArray::createWithCapacity(frames);
    char str[100] = {0};
    for(int i = 1; i <= frames; i++)
    {
        sprintf(str, "%s%d.png", animation_name.getCString(), i);
        CCSpriteFrame* frame = _cache->spriteFrameByName( str );
        animframes->addObject(frame);
    }
    _charanimation[a] = CCAnimate::create(CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(animframes, delay));
    //_charanimation[a]->getAnimation()->setLoops(-1);
}
```

and I get the animation to work (the one I set with `runAction()`) but if I try to change the animation, for example, when I touch the screen:

```
void HelloWorld::ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event)
{
    action++;
    action%=5;
    _character->stopAllActions();
    _character->runAction( CCRepeatForever::create(_charanimation[action]));
    char str[100];
    sprintf(str, "Animation: %d", action);
    pLabel->setString(str);

}
```

it crashes... I don't know if I am doing it wrong, if anyone could help, I will appreciate.

If I change the animation in `runAction()` it shows the animation correctly, but I can't change ingame with touches.

by the way, this is the error I get in console:

```
cocos2d-x debug info Assert failed: reference count should greater than 0
In function retain -- ..\..\cocoa\CCObject.cpp:92 m_uReference > 0 -- assertion failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because the `CCAnimate` object you have created is **autorelease** object and you are not **retaining** the object. **Autorelease** objects will be deleted automatically if they are not **retained**, either explicitly or by some other object.

While adding to array You can do

```
CCAnimate *animate = CCAnimate::create(CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(animframes, delay));
animate->retain();
_charanimation[a] = animate;
```

**do not forget to release** all the objects in the array when everything is over

```
_charanimation[index]->release();
```

- Note:

  Instead of using the simple C or C++ array you can use Cocos2d's `CCArray` which **retains** the object once it is added to the array.

For Example: **(The memory handling is similar to Objective-C)**

```
_charanimation = new CCArray();

//To add object to array
_charanimation->addObject(object);  //This will retain the object

//To get an object
_charanimation->objectAtIndex(index);
_charanimation->lastObject();
_charanimation->randomObject();

//To remove object
_charanimation->removeObjectAtIndex(index);  //This will release object
_charanimation->removeObject(object);        //This will release object

//Dont forget delete array later
delete (_charanimation);
```

[You can refer this link for more on CCArray](http://cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/CCArray)

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much, I didn't know that some cocos2d objects release themselves. Can you please post an example on how to make it work with CCArray, I don't know how to get the objects once I added to the CCArray. I'm still learning how to use it

Comment: I have another question... how can I make all this stuff into one class (lets say a player class) and then integrate it into the init? I tried and it crashes, I think I'm not managing the batchnodes and cache well, maybe it can't be part of a separated class, I don't know, I need examples... can you help me? I need a class that I can pass the .png and .plist (with any additional info needed) and have a method that I can call like PlayAnimation(index); so I can create something like Player p1, p2; and in some part of the code I could run p1.PlayAnimation(2); p2.PlayAnimation(0);

Comment: I have added an example to the answer. You can refer to the link there  for more on `CCArray`

Comment: Does adding object without retaining it to an unretained array - as mentioned in the last snippet of code - will retain the object ? or i have to retain the array to automatically retain the objects ?